# How to align the text in a flex with logos

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to make a duplicate of twitter for practice and I am stuck at a problem. I have a flex row and it contains a logo and a text. I want to align the text just like the logos are aligned. Please refer to the picture below. As you can see all the logos are aligned but the text is not aligned. I have tried adding `flex-direction: row;` and specifying the `row-gap` but it didn't work. I also tried using `flex-direction: column` incase it could give me my desired output but as soon as I enter `flex-direction:column` the logo and the text move to separate lines. Is there a simple way to align the text? Also, if you run the snippet and hover over each logo, you would notice that the background color changes and for every logo the padding is different for text written with the logo. The padding for the logo is alright. How can I make the margin so that the padding remains the same for both the logo and the text?
[image]

Find my code below.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
#container{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100vh;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
}
#logo{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 10em;
}
.fab{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#navlinks{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#home{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.logohome{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    flex: 50%;
}
.texthome{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left:2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
    flex: 50%;
}
#home:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#hashtag{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 9em;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-direction: row;
    row-gap: 20px;
}
.hashlogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.hashtext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#hashtag:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#notification{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.notilogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.notitext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#notification:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#messages{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.msglogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.msgtext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#messages:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#bookmark{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bkmrklogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.bkmrktext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#bookmark:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#lists{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.listslogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.liststext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#lists:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#profile{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.profilelogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.profiletext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#profile:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#more{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.r-1fmj7o5{
    height: 23px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.morelogo{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.moretext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#more:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}
#twtbtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
}
button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 15em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(112, 112, 245);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(130, 130, 252);
}
#middlecontainer{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 22em;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="navlinks">
            <div id="home">
                <div class="logohome"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
                <div class="texthome"><h4>Home</h4></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hashtag">
            <div class="hashlogo"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i></div>
            <div class="hashtext"><h4>Explore</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="notification">
            <div class="notilogo"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></div>
            <div class="notitext"><h4>Notifications</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="messages">
            <div class="msglogo"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></div>
            <div class="msgtext"><h4>Messages</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bookmark">
            <div class="bkmrklogo"><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i></div>
            <div class="bkmrktext"><h4>Bookmark</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="lists">
            <div class="listslogo"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></div>
            <div class="liststext"><h4>Lists</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="profile">
            <div class="profilelogo"><i class="far fa-user"></i></i></div>
            <div class="profiletext"><h4>Profile</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="more">
            <div class="morelogo"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-1fmj7o5 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-lwhw9o r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr"><g><circle cx="17" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="7" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path></g></svg></div>
            <div class="moretext"><h4>More</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="twtbtn">
            <div class="button"><button type="submit" value="Tweet">Tweet</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middlecontainer">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <h1></h1>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't understand why you used different class names?!
But your problem will be fix if you set an specific width size to your div

For example:

```
.logohome,.hashlogo{
  width:20px;
 }
```

Comment: If you take the div with id <code>#home</code> and apply width, it will change nothing. I applied different class names within each div for each logo and each text in order to make them separate items and apply rules to them differently.

Comment: My answer was not clear so I edited it, it can help you @AliMustafa

Comment: Try to remove all menus id's and use class names. This is good practice.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciated. Could you please look at what could be the possible reason why the padding for the text is not the same when you hover over every div? The padding is the same for every logo but for texts, it is different.

Comment: In another answer I fixed it, if I got it right, check it out @AliMustafa

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
#container{
    width: 25%;
    height: 100vh;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
}
#logo{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 10em;
}
.fab{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#navlinks{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 1em;
    flex-direction:column;
    min-width:250px;
}
#navlinks>div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#navlinks>div:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.192);
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.logohome{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:20px;
}
.texthome{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left:2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.hashlogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:20px;
}
.hashtext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.notilogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.notitext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.msglogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.msgtext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.bkmrklogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.bkmrktext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.listslogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.liststext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.profilelogo{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.profiletext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.r-1fmj7o5{
    height: 23px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.morelogo{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.moretext{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#twtbtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5.8em;
}
button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 15em;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(112, 112, 245);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(130, 130, 252);
}
#middlecontainer{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 22em;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="navlinks">
            <div id="home">
                <div class="logohome"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
                <div class="texthome"><h4>Home</h4></div>
            </div>
        
        <div id="hashtag">
            <div class="hashlogo"><i class="fas fa-hashtag"></i></div>
            <div class="hashtext"><h4>Explore</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="notification">
            <div class="notilogo"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></div>
            <div class="notitext"><h4>Notifications</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="messages">
            <div class="msglogo"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></div>
            <div class="msgtext"><h4>Messages</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bookmark">
            <div class="bkmrklogo"><i class="far fa-bookmark"></i></div>
            <div class="bkmrktext"><h4>Bookmark</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="lists">
            <div class="listslogo"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></div>
            <div class="liststext"><h4>Lists</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="profile">
            <div class="profilelogo"><i class="far fa-user"></i></i></div>
            <div class="profiletext"><h4>Profile</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div id="more">
            <div class="morelogo"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" class="r-1fmj7o5 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-lwhw9o r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr"><g><circle cx="17" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="7" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z"></path></g></svg></div>
            <div class="moretext"><h4>More</h4></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="twtbtn">
            <div class="button"><button type="submit" value="Tweet">Tweet</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middlecontainer">
        <nav id="navbar">
            <h1></h1>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would help, but I would try to put both the `text` and `logo` div tags in one block-level element (I have found that putting it in a

tag works pretty well.) After that you could align them inside that...